# Booting an unavailable Windows 7 Install

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcd

I had a drive with a full Win 7 install on it, but I installed a new Win 7 to a different drive, and the Boot configuration on that drive was completely removed. What would be the easiest way to reinstate that boot config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a Windows 7 installation on your computer which does not have a corresponding boot menu entry you have to add it.

1. Download and install [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net)
   The tool comes with "Dual-boot Repair" utility which can solve automatically dual-boot issues.
2. Run Dual-boot Repair (DBR) and click on "Disk Management" - verify that you first primary partition is marked as active ! If not mark it as active.
3. Click "Automatic Repair" in DBR. This will repair Windows 7 boot environment (MBR, PBR, BCD)
4. Reboot
5. Run Visual BCD Editor - right click and select "Create missing Windows loaders". This will create boot loaders for all visible installed Windows systems (XP, Vista, Windows 7) on your computer if not already present in Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store.

(Visible installation is a installation on a mapped drive - e.g. has a drive_letter associated with it.)